# Can I use Google flight api without an Api Key with the free quota (demo) in Java program

Tags: google-api, google-authentication, google-qpx-express-api

I want to use the google flight api in a non production way, I 'm develloping in java, I know that there is a free quota limited to 50 req/day, but how can use it having the search request requires an Api Key? Thank's

Comment: I am pretty sure all of the Google APIs now require that you at the very least use the API key this is the only way they have of knowing who is using the API.

Comment: The api key is not free even for free quota?

Comment: APIKey is used for the public APIs.  Stuff that doesn't require authentication to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure you are trying to use the QPX Express API,  this API requires that you send Key. or an access token from the OAuth2 authentication process.  The reason these keys are required even for the free quota is that Google needs to know who is hitting there API, even if like you say its a non production way.  They still need to know how is doing it.

Documentation [QPX Express API](https://developers.google.com/qpx-express/v1/trips/search)

> The key parameter is required with every request, unless you provide
>   an OAuth 2.0 token with the request.

Key Parameter:

> key   API key. (REQUIRED*)
>   *Required unless you provide an OAuth 2.0 token. Your API key identifies your project and provides you with API access, quota, and
>   reports. Obtain your project's API key from the Google Developers
>   Console.